# Add Help Text for User Roles Field on User Edit Page

Tags: hooks, users

I would like to add some help text for one of the fields displayed on the admin user edit page (the page seen when an admin edits a user account).

The help text would provide a brief description of each role that could be selected.

Is there some hook I can use to update the admin form?

[image: Screen capture of user roles selection]

Answer (score 3):

You can able to do it using [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) or using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a custom module..

You can add help text either using [#suffix](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#suffix) form attribute or [#description](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#description) attribute..

Comment: I used the following code sniglet to access the description in the hook_form_alter function: $form['account']['roles']['#description']  = 'My fancy description!";

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom module, implement `hook_form_alter` to add the `#description` form key and text value to the form in question.

I recommend the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module to find the name of the form and it's structure by using `dpm($form)` and `dpm($form_id)` within your `hook_form_alter`.